# Correspondence between binary numbers and $ab = \Pi_{i=1}^m p_i^{k_i}$ s.t. $a, b$ have no common factors

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'll note that $p_i$ is prime and $k_i \in \mathbb Z^+.$ I read in a textbook that the number of integers $ab = \Pi_{i=1}^m p_i^{k_i}$ s.t. $a, b$ have no common factors is $2^m$ which is the number of binary numbers of length $m$. I am trying to understand how they got $2^m$.

Initally I thought I understood how they came about the answer by considering $a = 2^i3^j5^k7^l, \ b = 11^a13^b17^c$ in which case $a$ is of the form $x\cdot x\cdot x \cdot x \cdot1\cdot1\cdot 1$ where $x$ is a factor of $a$. This form of $a$ is similar to a binary number. But then the latter is a sequence and the former is a product meaning order in $a$ doesn't matter. So I don't think I undeerstand what they did. Can someone, please, elaborate on how such products are counted? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice first that in order to not have common factors, then either $p_i^{k_i}|a$ or $p_i\not | a,$ you can not have any other option otherwise you are separating that prime into the two numbers $a,b$ and so they will have a factor in common. Now, label the primes as either $0$ or $1$ if your label is $1$ then you make it belong to $a$ and otherwise is in $b.$ Notice that this labelling is a bijection in between the different tuples $(a,b)$ having the desired property and the number of labellings, but the labellings are just binary words of size $m$ so there are $$\underbrace{2\times 2\times \cdots \times 2}_{m\text{ times}}=2^m.$$
Inspired in your example: $ab = 2^i3^j5^k$ you have 
$a=1,b=2^i3^j5^k$ so $000$
$a=2^i,b=3^j5^k$ so $100$
$a=3^j,b=2^i5^k$ so $010$
$a=5^j,b=2^i3^j$ so $001$
$a=2^i5^j,b=3^j$ so $101$
etc...

Also, notice that there is a symmetry in the problem, meaning that if you do not care who is $a$ and who $b$ then you are counting some things twice and the result has to be
$$2^{m-1}.$$

Comment: Since $ab$ is not ordered, $ab = 2^i3^j5^k = 3^j2^i5^k.$ If $a = 2^i5^k, b = 3^j$, then $ab$ corresponds to two binaries $101$ and $011$. How do we resolve this?

Comment: they are already ordered by the normal order on integers. So $011$ is $3^j5^k$ instead,

Comment: @user33558 By that i mean that the commutativity let us take an order and then do the sequences with the previously established order